# AngularJS and Asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on a project that has a layout.cshtml, which defines several sections of the layout.  What I now want is in a div that is on the to layout.cshtml specify which AngularJS controller I should use.

Thus the index.cshtml should specify - indexcontroller.
The account.cshml should specify - accountcontroller.

Can I use some sort of renderAttribute based on code below in the specific page?  Can I move the div to the specific section but still keep my content in my main layout page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used ViewBag to achieve this before.

In your Account Controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.AngularController = "accountcontroller"
        return View();
    }
}
```

Then in your layout you can simply use the property set on the ViewBag:

```
<div ng-controller="@ViewBag.AngularController">
    {{AngularGoodnessHere}}
</div>
```